# PubNub EON chart not Rendering Data

Tags: javascript, python, charts, pubnub

I am trying to render a spline chart with [PUBNUB EON charting library](https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart). I do not understand what is going wrong here. I can  see the data in console, but the chart is not rendering, there are only x and y axis lines. I am getting the data from python SDK and subscribing via javascript SDK. There is no error message in the console.

My python code is

```
def counterVolume(data):
  for each in data:
    y = each.counter_volume
    data_clean = json.dumps(y, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    print pubnub.publish(channel='channel', message= data_clean)


counterVolume(data)
```

My subscribe javascript function is

```
       var data;
       var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
                                publish_key: 'pub',
                                subscribe_key: 'subf'
                                            });

       var channel = "c3-spline";
                    eon.chart({
                             history: true,
                            channel: 'channel',
                             flow: true,
                               generate: {
                                bindto: '#chart',
                                data: {
                                x: 'x',
                                labels: false
                                        },
                               axis : {
                                  x : {
                                  type : 'timeseries',
                                  tick: {
                                 format: '%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
                                        }
    }
    } }});
    function dataCallback(){
                        pubnub.subscribe({
                                  channel: 'channel',
                                  message: function(m){
                                           data = m
                                           console.log(data)
          }
        });
        };
 dataCallback();
 pubnub.publish({
                     channel: 'orbit_channel',
                     message: {
                            columns: [
                                     ['x', new Date().getTime()],
                                     ['y', data]
              ]
            }
          })
```

I can see the values in console but I do not understand why it wont render on chart.

[image: here is what I see in the browser]

**the result of python script:**

```
89453.0
89453.0
89453.0
89453.0
```

Comment: Hi Hina,  Thank you for asking about Eon.  May you paste a sample result of your data (a JSON message) from your `Python Publish`?  Also I'm noticing your JavaScript has a `Subscribe` and a `Publish` call and that should be omitted.

Comment: @PubNub i have added the result to the above question please have look. even if I omit the publish function the chart wont render :(

Comment: Two possible issues: 1. Different pub/sub keys, just to make sure you are using identical keys to instantiate pubnub on python and javascript. 2. Could you print `data_clean` for us? `89453.0` is not a JSON object, EON requires a standard payload. My bet is there error lies there.

Comment: `89453.0` is validated as a literal that we support at PubNub as valid JSON.  However your answer is presented below as you need to ensure to use our `transform` method into EON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub EON Custom Streaming Chart Data Formats

PubNub EON requires a specific format in order to render and display your data on charts.  You can render any data format by using the built-in `transform` parameter which expects a `function(){}`. The transform function provided is treaded like a callback to a `map` operation and transforms your data to match the required EON format.

### PubNub EON Transform Method for Streaming Chart Data

Using the example stream from [PubNub Public Streams](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/data-streams/sensor-network).
You can use the `transform` method to format your message for EON.

#### EON Streaming Chart Data Format

```
{ columns : [
    ['x', new Date().getTime()],
    ['Humidity', m.humidity],
    ['Temperature', m.ambient_temperature],
    ['Light', m.photosensor]
] }
```

#### Example Streaming Chart Data Setup

Here is an example of a working PubNub stream being formatted for EON streaming chart.  Using the `transform` method, your JavaScript should look like this:

```
<script>
var pubnub = PUBNUB({
    subscribe_key : 'YOUR_SUBSCRIBE_KEY_HERE' // <-- CHANGE!!!
});

eon.chart({
    pubnub   : pubnub,
    history  : false,
    channel  : 'channel', // <-- YOUR CHANNEL
    flow     : true,
    generate : {
        bindto : '#chart',
        data   : {
            x      : 'x',
            labels : true
        },
        axis : {
            x : {
                type : 'timeseries',
                tick : {
                    format : '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    transform : function(data) {
        return { columns : [
            ['x', new Date().getTime()],
            ['Value', data]
        ] };
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped :)